# Regex matching end of a line $ not working in Bash Script

Tags: regex, bash, eol, parameter-expansion

I'm trying to do a simple regex statement in a bash script that will match and substitute the end of a word.  Below is what I'm trying to do.

```
wordh > word:’
```

Below is the code I'm using.

```
#!/bin/bash
STAT=${STAT/h$/:’}
```

I'm not familiar with bash scripting and I'm thinking it has something to do with the `$` because it's used to mark a variable.  I've tried to escape it as well as adding another `/` after it.  When I remove the `$` it works (without checking the end of a word).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex's there are a little different.
Try:

```
STAT=${STAT/%h/:’}
```

From the man page:

> ${parameter/pattern/string}
>
> ```
> .         The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname
>           expansion.   Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pat-
>           tern against its value is replaced  with  string.   If  Ipattern
>           begins  with /, all matches of pattern are replaced with string.
>           Normally only the first match is replaced.   If  pattern  begins
>           with  #, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of
>           parameter.  If pattern begins with %, it must match at  the  end
>           of  the expanded value of parameter.  If string is null, matches
>           of pattern are deleted and the / following pattern may be  omit-
>           ted.   If  parameter  is  @  or *, the substitution operation is
>           applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the  expansion
>           is  the  resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable sub-
>           scripted with @ or *, the substitution operation is  applied  to
>           each  member  of  the  array  in  turn, and the expansion is the
>           resultant list.
> ```

Comment: More like, it's not a regex at all.

Comment: It's a regex if extglob is enabled, but by default it's not.

Answer (score 0):

$ is not part of the word

you can try

```
    STAT=wordh\$
```

than try

```
     STAT=${STAT/h$/:’}
```